# Two different ways of presenting the ring of S-integers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, integers, ramification

Ok, first, here is my question:

Let $O$ be a Dedekind domain, $K$ its quotient field and let $S$ be a finite set of prime ideals in $O$. Let

$A:=\{x\in K: \forall\mathfrak{p}\not\in S\ (v_\mathfrak{p}(x)\geq0) \}$

and

$B:=\{\frac{f}{g}\in K:\forall\mathfrak{p}\not\in S\ (g\not\equiv0\text{ mod }\mathfrak{p})\}$

Now my question is: why are the same?

Clearly, $B\subseteq A$ holds, because $v_\mathfrak{p}(\frac{f}{g})=v_\mathfrak{p}(f)-v_\mathfrak{p}(g)=v_\mathfrak{p}(f)\geq0$ as $v_\mathfrak{p}(g)=0$ and $f\in O$. But how does one argue for the converse? I am somehow stuck... I strongly guess that the argument should be fairly easy... something like: if $v_\mathfrak{p}(\frac{f}{g})\geq0$ then there exist $f^\prime, g^\prime$ such that $\frac{f}{g}=\frac{f^\prime}{g^\prime}$ and $g^\prime\not\equiv0\text{ mod }\mathfrak{p}$.

In order to get the context right: $A$ is what usually is called the ring of $S$-integers (well, I know that what I wrote is a little bit out of context since usually one only considers the case where $O=O_K$ for a number field $K$ but I hope that everybody is fine with that). To make the context more precise, the definition of $A$ is basically from:

1. Neukirch, Schmidt, Wingberg: Cohomology of Number Fields, Ch. VIII, § 3

and the definition of $B$ is from

2. Neukirch: Algebraic Number Theory, Ch. I, § 11

Comment: How do you define $v_{\mathfrak p}(x)$ for $x\in K$?

Comment: @Ferra: for $x\in O$, $v_\mathfrak{p}(x)$ the unique number $n$ such that $x\in \mathfrak{p}^n\setminus\mathfrak{p}^{n+1}$ (where, by convention, $v_\mathfrak{p}(0)=\infty$) and for $x=\frac{f}{g}\in K$ that's extended to $v_\mathfrak{p}(f)-v_\mathfrak{p}(g)$. In case that $O$ is the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ of a number field $K$, the above $v_\mathfrak{p}(x)$ should coincide (unless I have misunderstood sth. completely) with the exponential valuation of the completion $K_\mathfrak{p}$ of $K$.

Comment: Have you tried using unique factorisation of ideals in $\mathcal O$?

Comment: @Mathmo123: how does that help me in getting the desired $f^\prime$ and $g^\prime$?

Comment: Write $(x) = \frac{\mathfrak p_1\cdots\mathfrak p_n}{\mathfrak q_1\cdots\mathfrak q_m}$. By assumption, $\mathfrak p\ne\mathfrak q_i$ for all $i$. Since $(x)$ is principal, both the numerator and denominator are in the same ideal class. So choose some ideal $\mathfrak a$ that is prime to $\mathfrak p$ such that $\mathfrak p_1\cdots\mathfrak p_n\mathfrak a$ and $\mathfrak q_1\cdots\mathfrak q_n\mathfrak a$ are both principal.

Comment: @Mathmo123: Ok, I almost got it. I can clearly see that $\mathfrak{a}$ can be chosen such that both $\mathfrak{p}_1\dots\mathfrak{p}_n\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{q}_1\dots\mathfrak{q}_m\mathfrak{a}$ are principal. What I don't see is why $\mathfrak{a}$ can be chosen prime to $\mathfrak{p}$ (sorry for stupidity - I'm still not used to calculate with ideals instead of numbers; neither do I have embraced the fact that $Cl(K)$ is finite). Cool!

Comment: Well, as an example, you could take $\mathfrak a$ to be some power of $\mathfrak q_1\cdots\mathfrak q_m$ (since the class group is finite :) )

Comment: @Mathmo123: To be honest, I already had such an $\mathfrak{a}$ in mind. But I forgot for a moment that being in the same class means that in fact ANY $\mathfrak{a}$ making $\mathfrak{p}_1\dots\mathfrak{p}_n\mathfrak{a}$ principal also makes $\mathfrak{q}_1\dots\mathfrak{q}_m\mathfrak{a}$ principal (and vice versa). Thanks a lot.

Comment: I will shortly write an answer :-)

Comment: When $K$ is a number field then it is also $\{\frac{f}{g},f,g \in O_K, (g)$ is a principal ideal which is a product of primes in $S\}$

Answer (score 1):

Just for a completion, I give an answer to my question myself which was in fact already answered in the comments thanks to Mathmo123. The argument is basically as already indicated in the question: take $x\in K$ such that $v_\mathfrak{p}(x)\geq0$. In order to find $f^\prime,g^\prime\in O$ such that $x=\frac{f^\prime}{g^\prime}$ and $g^\prime\not\equiv0\text{ mod }\mathfrak{p}$, by unique factorization in $O$ (and hence of fractional ideals over $K$), we can write $(x)=\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b}^{-1}$ with ideals $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ such that $\mathfrak{p}\mid\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{b}=O$. This means that $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ differ only by a fractional principal ideal; hence, the classes $\overline{\mathfrak{a}}$ of  $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\overline{\mathfrak{b}}$ of $\mathfrak{b}$ in $Cl(K)$ are the same. Now since $Cl(K)$ is finite, we can choose $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathfrak{b}^{n+1}$ is principal, say $\mathfrak{b}^{n+1}=(g^\prime)$ (note that $g^\prime\not\equiv0\text{ mod }\mathfrak{p}$. Hence, as $\overline{\mathfrak{a}}=\overline{\mathfrak{b}}$, also $\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b}^n$ is principal, say $\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b}^n=(\tilde f)$. Now we calculate
\begin{equation}
(x)=\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b}^{-1}=(\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b}^n(\mathfrak{b}^{n+1})^{-1}=(\tilde f)(g^\prime)^{-1}=(\frac{\tilde f}{g^\prime}).
\end{equation}
However, that means that $x$ and $\frac{\tilde f}{g^\prime}$ can differ only by a unit, say $\varepsilon$, so setting $f^\prime=\varepsilon\tilde f$ completes the proof.

I hope the answer is not too long for such a short problem; however, it helped me a lot in understanding the class group (what is actually not at all what I wanted but still...).

Comment: Looks good! You want $\mathfrak p\nmid \mathfrak b$ instead of $\mathfrak p\mid a$.

Comment: Your answer is good. Potential refinement as Mathmo123 said: possibly $\mathfrak{p}|\mathfrak{a}$ and necessarily $\mathfrak{p}\nmid\mathfrak{b}$ for $\mathfrak{p}\in S.$

Comment: @Mathmo123 Sorry for the late answer. First, let me say again thank you so much for your answer. It helped me a lot for my PhD exam. I did my PhD in computability theory, but my exam was also in Algebraic Number Theory (Leopoldt conjecture). Now in order to react to your comments, maybe I understood something completely wrong, but I wrote that $\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{b}=O$, so if $\mathfrak{p}\mid\mathfrak{a}$ then necessarily $\mathfrak{p}\not\mid\mathfrak{b}$ since $\mathfrak{p}$ is principal, right? And we can clearly choose $\mathfrak{a}$ with...

Comment: ...$\mathfrak{p}\mid\mathfrak{a}$ since $v_\mathfrak{p}(x)\geq0$, right? Does this resolve the issues or do I have to argue differently here?

Comment: @MartinMonath it's true that if $\mathfrak p\mid\mathfrak a$ implies that $\mathfrak p\nmid\mathfrak b$. But There's no need for $\mathfrak p$ to divide either of them!

Comment: @Mathmo123 Ok, maybe I oversaw something. Let's make a case distinction: a) $v_\mathfrak{p}(x)=0$ and b) $v_\mathfrak{p}(x)>0$ (these are all cases possible by assumption on the ring $A$). In case a) I guess we need to argue as you and user623904 suggested just because $\mathfrak{p}$ doesn't show up in the prime decomposition of $(x)$. But do you agree with me that my argument definitely goes through in case b)? Because I can split up the finite prime ideal product of $(x)$ into those prime ideals whose exponent is positive and those whose isn't. Now I take $\mathfrak{a}$ as the product...

Comment: of the first type and $\mathfrak{b}$ as the product of the second one. Then clearly $\mathfrak{p}\mid\mathfrak{a}$ holds by case assumption and $\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{b}=O$ holds because $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ don't share any common factors.

Comment: Yes that's correct! However, the condition $\mathfrak p\nmid \mathfrak b$ deals with both cases at once.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Oh my goodness gracious. Yes of course!!! Now I see it... sorry for being so stubborn. Yep... $\mathfrak{p}\not\mid\mathfrak{b}$ is the condition that I want. Thanks! :-D