# Is ring of $S$-integers a Dedekind domain?

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

For $\mathcal{O}_{K}$, the integer ring of a global field, we denote $S$ to be any set of primes of a global field $K.$ Let
 $$\mathcal{O}_{K,S}:=\{x\in K\mid v_{\mathfrak{p}}\geq 0\text{ for }\mathfrak{p}\notin S\}$$ be the ring of $S$-integers of $K$ (see Neukirch, Schmidt, Wingberg *Cohomology of Number Fields*, Ch. VIII, § 3).

A ring $R$ is Dedekind iff $R$ is a Noetherian integrally closed domain where the height of its prime ideals is $1.$
The Prop.1 in Bourbaki *Commutative Algebra*, Ch.VII.1 tells us that if $$S=\{\text{all primes of }K\}-\{\text{finitely many primes}\},$$ then $\mathcal{O}_{K,S}$ is Dedekind.

I guess $\mathcal{O}_{K,S}$ is not a Dedekind domain except for some special $K$ if $S$ is finite.
But I failed in a clear proof that $\mathcal{O}_{K,S}$ is Dedekind or not for $S$ to be finite.

Due to my poor knowledge in commutative algebra, it will great if there will be an explicit proof.

Please forgive me for the long description.

Comment: Yes, it is a Dedekind domain. Localization preserves noetherianity and integral closure, and in this case also dimension (because the dimension is 1 and you make sure S is big enough that at least one of the nonzero primes survives).

Comment: @TokenToucan Thanks for the useful two comments. Finally, the ring of S-integer is Dedekind if there is at least one non-trivial prime ideal in this ring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cO}{\mathcal{O}}$
$\newcommand{\cS}{\mathcal{S}}$

I'm also not super experienced, so do let me know if something here is unclear or seems wrong!

As you said, we need to show that $\cO_{K,\cS}$ is an integrally closed Noetherian domain of Krull dimension (length of longest chain of prime ideals) one.

1. Suppose $\alpha$ is integral over $\cO_{K,\cS}$ and satisfies the relation
   $\alpha^d + a_{d-1}\alpha^{d-1} + \dots a_0 = 0$ with coefficients $a_i \in \cO_{K,\cS}$. Then, for any valuation $v$ corresponding to a prime $\mathfrak{p}$,

$$dv(\alpha) = v(a_{d-1}\alpha^{d-1} + \cdots a_0) \geq \min((d-1)v(\alpha)+v(a_{d-1}), \dots , v(a_0))$$

If $\mathfrak{p} \notin \cS$, then $v(a_i) \geq 0$ for all $i$, so it cannot be the case that $v(\alpha) < 0$. Thus, $\alpha \in \cO_{K,\cS}$, meaning that $\cO_{K,\cS}$ is integrally closed in its fraction field $K$.

2. As TokenToucan pointed out in the comments, the localization of a Noetherian ring is Noetherian, and $\cO_{K,S}$ is the localization with respect to the set of elements outside $\mathfrak{p}$ for all $\mathfrak{p} \notin \cS$ (if you don't see how to go from the valuation condition to ratios of elements check out [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3366605/two-different-ways-of-presenting-the-ring-of-s-integers?rq=1) answer). Alternately, an overkill way is to observe that the Krull-Akizuki Theorem tells us that subrings of the fraction field of a one-dimensional reduced (no nonzero nilpotents) Noetherian ring are also Noetherian. In our case, $\cO_K$ is one-dimensional and an integral domain and $\cO_{K,\cS}$ contains $\cO_K$ and is contained within $K$, the fraction field of $\cO_K$.
3. This follows from the Krull-Akizuki theorem, as it actually guarantees that (proper) subrings of $K$ containing $\cO_K$ are Noetherian and one-dimensional.

Putting this all together, unless I messed up, we have the desired result.

Comment: (1) I'm not sure this quite works because the RHS could be negative - also valuation is additive not multiplicative, (2) KA is kind of overkill, localization preserves noetherianity since every prime of the localization is of the form $S^{-1}I$ for $I$ in the original ring, and so the finite set of generators for $I$ works for $S^{-1}I$, (3) it is *not* the case that $\mathcal O_{K,S}$ is integral over $\mathcal O_K$, and it shouldn't be because the latter is integrally closed; in fact the dimension is not always 1 if you make $S$ so large that $\mathcal O_{K,S}$ is all of $K$.

Comment: (1) There was a typo (now fixed) sorry I missed a plus. If RHS is negative then $v(\alpha)$ is negative, but RHS will never be less than $(d-1)v(\alpha) > dv(\alpha)$, contradicting the inequality.
(2)  Oh yeah I'll edit to have this instead. 
(3) Whoops you're totally right. I'll remove that part.

Comment: Makes sense, looks good!

Comment: @bean Thank you and Token for such a nice answer. I think I was sucked in understanding the KA theorem. Here a proper application was given by showing in 1. and 2. that thm's conditions are satisfied in the present situation.